# Microsoft Graph API reports endpoint for GCC High not working?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access O365 reports via the Microsoft Graph API for a GCC High O365 tenant.  I'm getting an error "Resource not found for the segment 'reports'".  Should this be working or is there an issue with how I'm constructing the request?

The full trace is below,

Request =>

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7') HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.10.0
Authorization: Bearer <JWT TOKEN REMOVED>
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Host: graph.microsoft.us
```

Response =>

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 6d491a27-7343-48d5-b4df-0b47b26c5cb6
client-request-id: 6d491a27-7343-48d5-b4df-0b47b26c5cb6
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"USGov Iowa","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"USI"}}
Duration: 2.1605
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 24 Jul 2018 18:03:44 GMT

f1
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": " .",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6d491a27-7343-48d5-b4df-0b47b26c5cb6",
      "date": "2018-07-24T18:03:44"
    }
  }
}
0
```

Comment: Are you able to use this against a regular organization? I wonder [whether this feature is supported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/deployments) for a GCC deployment. There is a difference in which features are supported for the different clouds.If this isn't supported, we'll need to update [this topic](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/reportroot-concept-overview).

Comment: @MichaelMainer yes when I run the same REST query against a commercial O365 tenant and against graph.microsoft.com it works.  Is there any documentation about what endpoints are available in GCC / GCC High for the graph api?  It's not obvious to me if this is by design or if this is a bug. Also is there a roadmap or timeline of when functionality will be available?

Comment: I don't know of any documentation other than the one a linked to.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments

Reports is not yet supported for US Gov Graph according to Microsoft.com

[image: NotSupportedonUsGov]