# Office 365 Service Communications API for GCC High O365 tenant not working

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm trying to access O365 subscribed services via the Office 365 Service Communications API for a GCC High O365 tenant.
The Office 365 Service Communications API reference is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference.

On the basis of the API Reference, I add *ServiceHealth.Read* permission for my app registration.

[My Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3nGY.jpg)

Then, on the basis of document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-u-s-government-gcc-high-endpoints?view=o365-worldwide,
I changed the endpoint to manage.office365.us.

I send a request with token to query data.

```
https://manage.office365.us/api/v1.0/{tenant_identifier}/ServiceComms/Messages
```

But the response is an error :

```
{"error": {"code": "","message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."}}
```

My question is : Is there something worng with the endpoint? or the api is not support for the GCC Hight tenant? or the permission which id add is wrong?

Besides, I have the same question like this:[Microsoft Graph API reports endpoint for GCC High not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505303/microsoft-graph-api-reports-endpoint-for-gcc-high-not-working), any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a few weeks back. The answer that we received from Microsoft was that the Communications API is not available under GCC High yet (with no ETA).

Welcome to GCC High!